# SDL (And Others) Virtual Key Input

Tags: c++, events, sdl

Today I set up the input in my application for all the different keys. This works fine except for virtual keys, for example, caret or ampersand. Keys that normally need shift to be got at. Using SDL these virtual keys don't work. As in they do not register an event.

```
if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_CARET:
                Keys[KeyCodes::Caret] = KeyState::Down;
                break;
            case SDLK_UP:
                Keys[KeyCodes::Up] = KeyState::Down;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I am absolutely sure my system works with physical keys like Up. The program queries a keystate like so:

```
if (Keys[KeyCode] == KeyState::Down) {
    lua_pushboolean(L, true);
} else {
    lua_pushboolean(L, false);
}
```

KeyCode is passed in as an argument.

So why are virtual keys, or keys that need shift to get at not working using SDL's KeyDown event type? Is more code needed to get to them? Or am I being stupid?

Answer (score 1):

SDL only reports real key events.

The good news is you can [enable *Unicode translation*](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlenableunicode.html) to get symbols like '^' or '@'.

First put this in your initialization code:

```
SDL_EnableUNICODE(1);
```

Now `SDL_KEYDOWN` events will have the accompanying character in the `unicode` member of [`SDL_keysym`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlkeysym.html). This factors in shift, caps lock, etc., when translating the key press into a character. Keys like `SDLK_UP` will have `unicode == 0`.

This actually makes using `keysym.unicode` ideal for text input, especially when used with [`SDL_EnableKeyRepeat`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_EnableKeyRepeat).

Here's an example: on my keyboard, I hold `shift-6` to generate `^`. The program recieves an `SDL_KEYDOWN` event with `keysym.sym == SDLK_6`, and `keysym.unicode == '^'`.

The one caveat is that only key *press* events will be translated, not release events. But this should not be a big problem, since you shouldn't use text characters for game controls anyway, only real keys. And if you're doing text input with key repeating, it only matters when keys are pressed, not released.

You might have to mix-and-match using `keysym.sym` and `keysym.unicode` to fit your exact needs.

Comment: May I ask will it register a unicode event with or without pressing the shift key at the same time? or do I need to use Key modifiers?

Comment: Either. On my keyboard, 6 and ^ are on the same key. Without shift, `unicode` is `6`. With shift, `unicode` is `^`. The operating system fills in what it should be. So no need for checking key modifiers.

Comment: This might also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403251/unicode-input-handling-in-games

Comment: keysym.unicode is a Uint16 not an SDLKey like keysym.sym? How then are you able to tell what key corresponds to a unicode key event?

Comment: I should clarify. When I mention keysym, I'm talking about `event.key.keysym`. As well as having member `sym`, it has a member `unicode`. When processing events, just look at `sym` to tell you the key, and look at `unicode` to get the corresponding character, with modifiers applied. Look here: http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlkeysym.html

Comment: Ok thats a lot more complicated than it originally seemed? I hate to be a pain but how exactly do I tell if a unicode charater has been pressed? as in shift+6 to type ^?

Comment: In your code, just before `switch (event.key.keysym.sym)`, check if `event.key.keysym.unicode == '^'`, and handle it specially, else just handle it in the `switch`, exactly same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I do apologise for getting slightly frustrated but I have finally got some code to tell when some one has pressed on the Caret key for example. I do hope others find this useful information.

```
case SDLK_6:
    if (event.key.keysym.mod == KMOD_LSHIFT || event.key.keysym.mod == KMOD_RSHIFT) {
        Keys[KeyCodes::Caret] = KeyState::Down;
    } else {
        Keys[KeyCodes::n6] = KeyState::Down;
    }
    break;
```

Basically when checking normal keys that have a shift click special key then check the key modifier. I understand the unicode value now but this idea seems simpler for now.

Again thanks for all the help!

Comment: The only problem with this is keyboard layouts. Keys like @ and ^ are often in different places, depending what country you're in, even for QWERTY keyboards. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#QWERTY